# Trying to update to 12.10 but Update Manager not showing update for it

Tags: upgrade

When I go to update to 12.10 from 12.04.02, the update manager is not showing that there is an update for Ubuntu and the konsole is saying that I have 12.04.02 when I see what release is on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `update-manager` settings to show 12.10, since it's not an LTS release, and by default `update-manager` only shows available LTS updates.

To do so, follow these steps:

1. Open up `update-manager` through the `Dash`: tap on <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type in `update-manager`.
2. Click on `Settings`.
3. Under the `Updates` tab, change **`Notify me of a new Ubuntu version`** from the default `For long-term support versions` to `For any new version`.

For clarity, here's a screenshot:

[image: What I mean]

Answer (score 1):

yes, it won't show in update manager because

1. The version you are using 12.04.02 is an LTS version (long term support) and its probabbly the most stable version at the time.
2. The version i.e 12.10, you are trying to update from 12.04.x is not LTS which probably means the support will end after 18 months and its not the most recommended version but it has some more advance features than 12.04.xx so when it will come new version LTS in 2014 14.04 than it will show you a new update for LTS version to LTS.
3. If you are using non LTS version than it will show you whenever it will come a new version of ubuntu weather it is LTS or not.
4. To upgrade to 12.10 you have to change the settings of update manager to show all versions of ubuntu weather they are LTS or not

**My opinion**

You don't need to update your 12.04.2 to 12.10 because you are using the most stable version

Answer (score 0):

You can run `do-release-upgrade -d`

The -d flag is development. Which will upgrade to a development version. From 12.10 to 13.04, or 12.04 to 12.10

I'm not sure if this is bad practise, but it worked for me.